# understanding Lagoms persistent read side

Tags: persistence, cqrs, lagom

I read through the Lagom documentation, and already wrote a few small services that interact with each other. But because this is my first foray into CQRS i still have a few conceptual issues about the persistent read side that i don't really understand.

For instance, i have a user-service that keeps a list of users (as aggregates) and their profile data like email addresses, names, addresses, etc.

The questions i have now are

- if i want to retrieve the users profile given a certain email-address, should i query the read side for the users id, and then query the event-store using this id for the profile data? or should the read side already keep all profile information?
- If the read side has all information, what is the reason for the event-store? If its truly write-only, it's not really useful is it?
- Should i design my system that i can use the event-store as much as possible or should i have a read side for everything? what are the scalability implications?
- if the user-model changes (for instance, the profile now includes a description of the profile) and i use a read-side that contains all profile data, how do i update this read side in lagom to now also contain this description?
- Following that question, should i keep different read-side tables for different fields of the profile instead of one table containing the whole profile
- if a different service needs access to the data, should it always ask the user-service, or should it keep its own read side as needed? In case of the latter, doesn't that violate the CQRS principle that the service that owns the data should be the only one reading and writing that data?

As you can see, this whole concept hasn't really 'clicked' yet, and i am thankful for answers and/or some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i want to retrieve the users profile given a certain email-address, should i query the read side for the users id, and then query the event-store using this id for the profile data? or should the read side already keep all profile information?

You should use a specially designed ReadModel for searching profiles using the email address. You should query the Event-store only to rehydrate the Aggregates, and you rehydrate the Aggregates only to send them commands, not queries. In CQRS an Aggregate may not be queried.

> If the read side has all information, what is the reason for the event-store? If its truly write-only, it's not really useful is it?

The Event-store is the source of truth for the write side (Aggregates). It is used to rehydrate the Aggregates (they rebuild their internal & private state based on the previous emitted events) before the process commands and to persist the new events. So the Event-store is append-only but also used to read the event-stream (the events emitted by an Aggregate instance). The Event-store ensures that an Aggregate instance (that is, identified by a type and an ID) processes only a command at a time.

> if the user-model changes (for instance, the profile now includes a description of the profile) and i use a read-side that contains all profile data, how do i update this read side in lagom to now also contain this description?

I don't use any other framework but my own but I guess that you rewrite (to use the new added field on the events) and rebuild the ReadModel.

> Following that question, should i keep different read-side tables for different fields of the profile instead of one table containing the whole profile

You should have a separate ReadModel (with its own table(s)) for each use case. The ReadModel should be blazing fast, this means it should be as small as possible, only with the fields needed for that particular use case. This is very important, it is one of the main benefits of using CQRS.

> if a different service needs access to the data, should it always ask the user-service, or should it keep its own read side as needed? In case of the latter, doesn't that violate the CQRS principle that the service that owns the data should be the only one reading and writing that data?

Here depends on you, the architect. It is preferred that each ReadModel owns its data, that is, it should subscribe to the right events, it should not depend on other ReadModels. But this leads to a lot of code duplication. In my experience I've seen a desire to have some canonical ReadModels that own some data but also can share it on demand. For this, in CQRS, there is also the term `query`. Just like commands and events, queries can travel in your system, but only from ReadModel to ReadModel.

Queries should not be sent during a client's request. They should be sent only in the background, as an asynchronous synchronization mechanism. This is an important aspect that influences the resilience and responsiveness of your system.

I've use also live queries, that are pushed from the authoritative ReadModels to the subscribed ReadModels in real time, when the answer changes.

> In case of the latter, doesn't that violate the CQRS principle that the service that owns the data should be the only one reading and writing that data?

No, it does not. CQRS does not specify *how* the `R` (Read side) is updated, only that the `R` should not process commands and `C` should not be queried.